# Bad populating values for child selectOneMenu JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have problem with populating values for child SelectOneMenu. When I change value in parent selectOneNode then values in child selectOneNode are removed instead insert new.

There is part of my xhtml file:

```
<a4j:region>
<h:selectOneMenu id="dict_trg" value="#{backingBean.trgDictId}" disabled="false" rendered="#{backingBean.itemEdited}">
    <c:forEach var="dict" items="#{backingBean.dictionaries}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{dict.name}" itemValue="#{dict.dicId}" />
    </c:forEach>
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" reRender="entry_trg" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>

<br />
<br />


<h:selectOneMenu id="entry_trg" value="#{backingBean.trgEntryId}" disabled="false" rendered="#{backingBean.itemEdited}">
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="#{backingBean.trgDictionaryEntries}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{entry.localizedName}" itemValue="#{entry.dntId}" />
    </c:forEach>
</h:selectOneMenu>
</a4j:region>
```

And there method responsible for get List entries for selectOneMenu

```
public List<Dictionary> getDictionaries(){
    return getDictionaryDataManager().getDictionaries();    
}

public List<DictionaryEntry> getTrgDictionaryEntries(){
      getDictionaryDataManager().getDictionary(12); 
}
```

I checked that methods and they always returns list with few items. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<f:selectItems>` if you have a collection of items, using `<c:forEach>` for this is what breaks it (you cannot partially rerender something built with `<c:xyz>`).

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="dict_trg" value="#{backingBean.trgDictId}" disabled="false" rendered="#{backingBean.itemEdited}">
    <f:selectItems var="dict" value="#{backingBean.dictionaries}" itemLabel="#{dict.name}" itemValue="#{dict.dicId}" />
    <a4j:support ajaxSingle="true" event="onchange" reRender="entry_trg" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```